# How to use json array to extract different values from JSON document?

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, select

I am using `8.0.18-commercial` and written following `MySQL` query to form `cross join with JSON documents` .

Please note that the number of entries in `servers[]` is same as number of entries in `objectIds[]`
There is meant to be one entry in `servers[]` corresponding to an entry in `objectIds[]`

```
SELECT t1.networkInfo->>"$.*" AS network, 
t1.objectIds,
j.server
FROM table1 t1
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(t1.servers, 
                      "$[*]" COLUMNS (
                        server VARCHAR(20) PATH '$'
                        )
                      ) j
WHERE t1.id = 56
```

### Output

```
network                             server                  objectIds
["abc.com", "Linux123", "RHEL"]     Server123       ["objectId123", "objectId1231", "objectId1232"]
["abc.com", "Linux123", "RHEL"]     Server1231      ["objectId123", "objectId1231", "objectId1232"]
["abc.com", "Linux123", "RHEL"]     Server1232      ["objectId123", "objectId1231", "objectId1232"]
```

I want to add another join in the query so that the output looks as below:

### Expected Output

```
network                             server           objectIds
["abc.com", "Linux123", "RHEL"]     Server123        objectId123
["abc.com", "Linux123", "RHEL"]     Server1231       objectId1231
["abc.com", "Linux123", "RHEL"]     Server1232       objectId1232
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result you want by unpacking the `objectIds` column in the same way as the `servers` column, adding a row number column to each [`JSON_TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) using `FOR ORDINALITY` and using that row number to `JOIN` the `servers` and `objectIds` tables:

```
SELECT t1.networkInfo->>"$.*" AS network, s.server, o.objectId
FROM table1 t1
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(t1.servers, 
                      "$[*]" COLUMNS (
                        rownum FOR ORDINALITY,
                        server VARCHAR(20) PATH '$'
                        )
                      ) s
JOIN JSON_TABLE(t1.objectIds, 
                "$[*]" COLUMNS (
                  rownum FOR ORDINALITY,
                  objectId VARCHAR(20) PATH '$'
                  )
                ) o ON o.rownum = s.rownum
WHERE t1.id = 56
```

Output:

```
network                             server      objectId
["abc.com", "Linux123", "RHEL"]     Server123   objectId123
["abc.com", "Linux123", "RHEL"]     Server1231  objectId1231
["abc.com", "Linux123", "RHEL"]     Server1232  objectId1232
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iS7rdkTUs97U9WmzGFsnnp/0)

Comment: I am getting `null` for `objectId` values

Comment: `    network                             server           objectIds
    ["abc.com", "Linux123", "RHEL"]     Server123        NULL
    ["abc.com", "Linux123", "RHEL"]     Server1231       NULL
    ["abc.com", "Linux123", "RHEL"]     Server1232       NULL`

Comment: Does your data look different to my demo?

Comment: I am able to make it work by changing `VARCHAR(20)` to `VARCHAR(40)`

Comment: Ah - yes, I only made the size of the varchar big enough to fit the data in the question... I'm glad you figured that out.